# How do I fix this procedure in Oracle SQL?

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ORDER_INFO (
I_ORDER_NUM in ORDERS.ORDER_NUM%TYPE)
AS
I_ORDER_DATE  ORDERS.ORDER_DATE%TYPE;
I_CUSTOMER_NUM ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE;
I_CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
INTO
I_ORDER_DATE, I_CUSTOMER_NUM, I_CUSTOMER_NAME FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER 
WHERE
ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM AND ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = I_ORDER_NUM;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_ORDER_DATE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_CUSTOMER_NUM);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I_CUSTOMER_NAME);
END;
/
```

I got tasked with:
Obtain the order date, customer number, and name for the order whose number currently is stored in I_ORDER_NUM. Place these values in the variables
I_ORDER_DATE, I_CUSTOMER_NUM and I_CUSTOMER_NAME, respectively.
Output the contents of I_ORDER_DATE, I_CUSTOMER_NUM, and
I_CUSTOMER_NAME.

I used the code above but I get the following:
"Error at line 8: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

6. I_CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE;
7. BEGIN
8. SELECT ORDER_DATE, CUSTOMER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NAME
9. INTO
10. I_ORDER_DATE, I_CUSTOMER_NUM, I_CUSTOMER_NAME FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER "

There should only be 1 input and I should get the outputs, but I get that error and I don't know what to do. As of writing this is late so maybe I'm missing something on the query. If someone could shed some light into my problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i see no error. can you please also share create statements of those table ?

Answer (score 1):

Column `CUSTOMER_NUM` is ambiguously defined in `SELECT` statement, as it belongs to both tables (`orders` and `customer`) so - without specifying which one you need - Oracle doesn't know which one to take.

Besides, I suggest you use table aliases and explicitly `JOIN` tables.

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE order_info (i_order_num IN orders.order_num%TYPE)
  2  AS
  3     i_order_date     orders.order_date%TYPE;
  4     i_customer_num   orders.customer_num%TYPE;
  5     i_customer_name  customer.customer_name%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7     SELECT o.order_date, o.customer_num, c.customer_name
  8       INTO i_order_date, i_customer_num, i_customer_name
  9       FROM orders o JOIN customer c ON o.customer_num = c.customer_num
 10      WHERE o.order_num = i_order_num;
 11
 12     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i_order_date);
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i_customer_num);
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (i_customer_name);
 15  END;
 16  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, did manage to understand my mistake and got your suggestion.